# Prune old files in a directory with phing

Tags: date, phing

This target  works fine

```
<target name="cleanlogs">
   <echo msg="clean log do nothing !!!!not ready!!!!" />
  <fileset dir="/var/www/myapp/log" id="deleteLogs">
   <include name="**/debug*.log" />
  </fileset>
  <delete>
   <fileset refid="deleteLogs" />
  </delete>
 </target>
```

I want add something like

```
<date datetime="xxxxxx" when="before"/>
```

or

```
<date seconds="xxxxxx" when="before"/>
```

to delete only logs older than 5 days

How to build xxxxx in phing ??

```
<tstamp>
```

dont return "timestamp" :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proposition of solution

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project name="Project" default="format"   basedir=".">
        <target name="format">
                <tstamp>
                        <format property="DATE" pattern="%s" />
                </tstamp>
                <php expression="${DATE}-(3600*24*5)" returnProperty="NEWDATE"/>
                <php expression="time()-(3600*24*5)" returnProperty="EVALUATEDTIME"/>

                <echo>DATE = ${DATE}</echo>
                <echo>NEWDATE = ${NEWDATE}</echo>
                <echo>EVALUATEDTIME = ${EVALUATEDTIME}</echo>

        </target>
    </project>
```

Actually you can put anything in the eval and directly compute whatever you need.